# Windows Azure: Creation of a file on cloud blob container

Tags: windows, azure, blob

I am writing a program that will be executing on the cloud. The program will generate an output that should be written on to a file and the file should be saved on the blob container.

I don't have a idea of how to do that

Will this code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
```

generate a file named "file" on the cloud...

---

Oh.. then how to store the content to the blob..

Comment: Perhaps you should read something like this: http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/windows-azure-blobs-and-blocks/

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to upload a Page blob or a Block blob?  Usually block blobs are what are required, unless you are going to create a VM from the blob image, then a page blob is needed.

Something like this works however.  This snippet taken from the most excellent [Blob Transfer Utility](https://blobtransferutility.codeplex.com/)  Check it out for all your upload and download blob needs.  (Just change the type from Block To Page if you need a VHD)

```
public void UploadBlobAsync(ICloudBlob blob, string LocalFile)
    {
        // The class currently stores state in class level variables so calling UploadBlobAsync or DownloadBlobAsync a second time will cause problems.
        // A better long term solution would be to better encapsulate the state, but the current solution works for the needs of my primary client.
        // Throw an exception if UploadBlobAsync or DownloadBlobAsync has already been called.
        lock (WorkingLock)
        {
            if (!Working)
                Working = true;
            else
                throw new Exception("BlobTransfer already initiated. Create new BlobTransfer object to initiate a new file transfer.");
        }

        // Attempt to open the file first so that we throw an exception before getting into the async work
        using (FileStream fstemp = new FileStream(LocalFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) { }

        // Create an async op in order to raise the events back to the client on the correct thread.
        asyncOp = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(blob);

        TransferType = TransferTypeEnum.Upload;
        m_Blob = blob;
        m_FileName = LocalFile;

        var file = new FileInfo(m_FileName);
        long fileSize = file.Length;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(m_FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        ProgressStream pstream = new ProgressStream(fs);
        pstream.ProgressChanged += pstream_ProgressChanged;
        pstream.SetLength(fileSize);
        m_Blob.ServiceClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 10;
        asyncresult = m_Blob.BeginUploadFromStream(pstream, BlobTransferCompletedCallback, new BlobTransferAsyncState(m_Blob, pstream));
    }
```